# MVC+ Url Routing+adding additional paramters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a url like http://mysite.ef.com/mine  . It internally needs to redirect to

http://mysite.ef.com/Product/ViewProduct/2. The last parameter(i.e 2) has to be derived from last paramter of the first url (in this case the value is "mine") by hitting the database to see if it is valid and if it is valid get the correct id. How can we accomplish it using Url Routing. I could  validate it by using custom constraint but how to rewrite the url with this fetched value.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Get your routing configuration to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "ProductRouting",
      url: "{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductView", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      namespaces: new[] { "YourApp.Controllers" }
);
```

Beware though, as the usual default route looks like this and if you just pass one parameter that usually specifies just the controller, but in your case it will specify the product id.

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      namespaces: new[] { "YourApp.Controllers" }
);
```

If you somehow need it to perform a lookup and work out that `mine` corresponds to product `2`, your `ProductView` `ActionMethod` needs to take in a string and perform a simple lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had implemented routing like what was suggested above. But in order  to prevent unnecessary redirection to the controller action if the paramter is not available in the database,I implemented custom constraint and hitting database there.Since we are doing the validation at routing level, I thought of getting the id as well and passing it on , else again need to hit the database at controller level

Comment: I would just send the request to the controller action and let it do the database lookup in there (via a call to a product service, of course). You still only need to hit the database once. In any case, is your issue now resolved?